Aspeger Syndrome, ADHD and shoteh
Does Asperger Syndrome make one a halakhic shoteh? And what about ADHD (Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder)?

https://yctorah.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Status-of-Persons-with-Mental-Confusion-and-Persons-with-Intellectual-Disorders-in-Halakha-Farbstein.pdf

AS definitely doesn't make one a shoteh, as it doesn't impair one's ability to understand or hold in halachah
